# Map ends at 0% Reduce Ends at 100%

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on a WordCount MapReduce program, I can get my code to run, but there is no output and the map finishes at 0% while the reduce finishes at 100%.

```
hadoop jar C:/wordCount.jar C:/project_1_data /myWordCount
2022-02-11 18:43:59,648 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
2022-02-11 18:43:59,788 WARN nativeio.NativeIO: NativeIO.getStat error (3): The system cannot find the path specified.
 -- file path: tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/camma/.staging
2022-02-11 18:43:59,809 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles: Permissions on staging directory /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/camma/.staging are incorrect: rwxrwx---. Fixing permissions to correct value rwx------
2022-02-11 18:43:59,996 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2022-02-11 18:44:00,025 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 0
2022-02-11 18:44:00,032 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0
2022-02-11 18:44:00,084 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1644626534356_0002
2022-02-11 18:44:00,084 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2022-02-11 18:44:00,188 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-02-11 18:44:00,189 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2022-02-11 18:44:00,222 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1644626534356_0002
2022-02-11 18:44:00,243 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Cameron:8088/proxy/application_1644626534356_0002/
2022-02-11 18:44:00,243 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1644626534356_0002
2022-02-11 18:44:04,303 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1644626534356_0002 running in uber mode : false
2022-02-11 18:44:04,303 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2022-02-11 18:44:08,353 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 100%
2022-02-11 18:44:08,357 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1644626534356_0002 completed successfully
2022-02-11 18:44:08,403 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 35
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=0
                FILE: Number of bytes written=235876
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
        Job Counters
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=1184
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=1184
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=1184
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=1212416
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=0
                Reduce shuffle bytes=0
                Reduce input records=0
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=0
                Shuffled Maps =0
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=3
                CPU time spent (ms)=77
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=223731712
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=451411968
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=257425408
                Peak Reduce Physical memory (bytes)=223731712
                Peak Reduce Virtual memory (bytes)=451428352
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=8
```

Here is my current code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

If I need to post copies of the files from setting up hadoop I can.

Comment: I'd remove the combiner until you have the mapper and reducer working. You can see 0 bytes read, which suggests your input path doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that Spark can do word-count in a lot less code